# simple sql query with distinct/count

Tags: mysql

select * from test;

```
+--------+------+  
| name   | age  |  
+--------+------+  
| asif   |   20 |  
| mithun |   20 |  
| vinod  |   21 |  
+--------+------+
```

I want o/p as below

```
age count
20   2
21   1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try it?

```
SELECT age,count(age) as count from test GROUP BY age
```

Comment: It should be ````SELECT age,count(age) as count from test GROUP BY age```` ;)

Comment: yeah, I forgot to add. but I edited:)